# autoload might not working in Codeigniter 4 in cloud machine

Tags: codeigniter-4, php-7.4

[image]I am getting the following error in amazone cloud (AWS)
`Class 'App\Controllers\My_Controller' not found`
but it works fine in my local.
i cant find whats the issue?

Comment: Did you check if Main,php in the controller folder starts with an uppercase?

Comment: yes, its upper case

Comment: and My_Controller? Also class name must be Uppercase too. It's most likely a naming convention error, as it works on your localhost

Comment: You are really great as you know mac is case in sensetive but the cloud machine  CenOs is case sensitive. Thank yo bro you save my time and job too.

Comment: a made my comment an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cloud servers (AWS), similar to Apache are case sensitive, your error is most likely deriving from a naming convention error, as it works on your localhost.

check that **My_Controller.php** and the **My_Controller class** are spelled correctly (1st letter uppercase and case sensitive)

Comment: Exactly you are right. This was the issue you mentioned.